# Is it possible to add custom markers to the Chrome React Profiler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-devtools

Using Chrome's "Performance" tab, I can add custom markers using `console.time`. With the React Devtool's "Profiler" tab, is it possible to show custom markers to help debug what's trigger each update?

There's an option labeled "Show inline warnings and errors.", so I expected `console.warn` and `console.error` to show up in the profiler, but they're not.

[image]

I also tried `unstable_trace`, but that didn't work because the "Interactions" subtab isn't showing up in my profiler (separate question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This isn't something React DevTools supports.

The "Interactions" tab was removed because the (experimental) tracing APIs were never released (and were removed before the 18 alpha).